# select row ExtJS6.2 viewport extends grid.panel

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, extjs6.2

I am trying to delete a selected row in my Viewport component that extends Ext.grid.panel. The below example allows me to select rows but it is instantiated as a grid.Panel not a Viewport. Is it possible to select a specific row with a viewPort that extends grid.Panel

similar: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ech
I've had various attempts but I believe my issue is that I cannot grab the grid.

My code

```
var mainView = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
//extends grid.panel
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

items: [{
    //xtype is used to re-use components or classes
    xtype: 'grid',
    store: userStore,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Email Address',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 2
    }, {
        text: 'Phone Number',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        flex: 2
    }]

}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'NEW',
    height: 50,
    width: '33%',
    handler: function () {
        var win = Ext.create('innerWindow');
        win.show();
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'VIEW',
    height: 50,
    width: '33%',
    handler: function () {
        var win = Ext.create('innerWindow');
        win.show();
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'DELETE',
    height: 50,
    width: '33%',
    handler: function () {
        let selected = grid.getSelection();
        //want to delete selected row
        //var record = userStore.getAt(0);
        userStore.remove(selected);
    }
}]
```

});

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Why would the process be any different for a grid subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give an id to your grid:

```
id: 'MyGrid'
```

Now you can reference the grid:

```
handler: function () {
        var grid = Ext.getCmp("MyGrid");
        var store = grid.getStore();
        var selection = grid.getView().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
        if (selection) {
            store.remove(selection);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to EXT JS and had been struggling with that for well over an hour but now thanks to you, I feel little more capable.